# How to completely remove installation of Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers

Tags: c++, eclipse

I installed Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers (on Linux) and then messed around with a lot of settings. For example, I installed an add-on to download and install color themes.

I want to completely remove the installation so I can install from scratch. To do this, I'm removing the following:

```
$ rm -rf /home/van/eclipse # <-- Eclipse installation directory.
$ rm -rf /home/van/.eclipse
$ rm -rf /home/van/eclipse_workspace
```

However, when I re-install using:

```
$ tar -zxvf eclipse-cpp-2019-12-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz -C /home/van/eclipse
```

and then start Eclipse, the previously installed color theme is still set, indicating there's another settings/add-ons directory somewhere that is still being used.

What other directories does Eclipse use to store add-ons/settings/configs?

Comment: You should see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282951/how-to-completely-uninstall-eclipse) on askubuntu to uninstall all dependencies.

Comment: What do you mean by _"previously installed color theme"_? Have you installed a color theme plug-in? If yes, the plug-in does obviously not follow Eclipse guidelines and saves its settings elsewhere. Which plug-in are you talking about exactly? There might be a folder `~/.<color_theme_plug-in_name>`.

Comment: @howlger The plugin I'm using is "DevStyles". I'm selecting a dark color theme and dark scheme for the editor. Those themes persist across re-installing.

Comment: @VanessaDeagan So it's not Eclipse. The DevStyles plug-in is closed source by Genuitec, therefore it is not possible to look into the source code to answer the questions. I know from other Genuitec plug-ins that Genuitec does not follow Eclipse conventions. Do you have folders whose names containing _devstyles, darkest dark theme, codemix, myeclipse, webclipse, genuitec_ or something like that? Or you [ask Genuitec directly](https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topics/devstyle/).

Comment: Thanks @howlger. I'm not confident using DevStyles as tucked away in the settings is the option to "opt out" of anonymous data being collected (I had no idea data is collected by default). I have performed a clean install of Manjaro KDE, and will look for other ways to apply color schemes/custom syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

I've got also `~/.cache/Eclipse/` folder here. Also there could be some data from that addon - try searching your home folder for addon's name.